# Pass <script> tags, or unsanitized values to handlebars layout?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I want to pass values that handlebars' handles don't sanitize upon output. For example ensuring that: `res.render('index', {script: '<script src="bundle.js"></script>'})` isn't rendered by `{{script}}` on the layout in the manner of `&lt script &gt`[...], as it currently does when I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `{{{script}}}` triple braces and handlebars won't sanitize the HTML.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Can't believe how I couldn't find it sooner